# Brave browser - sudo apt-get error

Tags: ubuntu, apt, package-management

I use Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with Brave browser just uninstalled.

I am trying to install some packages using the `sudo apt-get install`, I had already removed the brave browser but still it is showing up in the error message and I cannot install any package, and whenever I run the command I am getting the following error:

```
Ign:1 cdrom://Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20210209.1) focal InRelease
Hit:2 cdrom://Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20210209.1) focal Release
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                             
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                   
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                     
Get:7 https://brave-browser-apt-nightly.s3.brave.com stable InRelease [4316 B]                     
Err:7 https://brave-browser-apt-nightly.s3.brave.com stable InRelease                              
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0B31DBA06A8A26F9
Hit:8 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                            
W: GPG error: https://brave-browser-apt-nightly.s3.brave.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0B31DBA06A8A26F9
E: The repository 'https://brave-browser-apt-nightly.s3.brave.com stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I want to know that since I removed the brave browser why is it still showing up in the error message?

Answer (score 1):

The error message means that `apt` is configured to use repository `https://brave-browser-apt-nightly.s3.brave.com`, but when it tries to verify the repository, it fails because it does not have the public key which corresponds to the private key which the repository was signed with.

To remove the message, you can either remove the repository or get the public key.

The repository from the error message is for the Nightly Channel. You can add the public key by repeating the instruction on getting the key from the [installation manual from the Brave's site](https://brave.com/linux/#nightly-channel-installation):

```
sudo curl -fsSLo /usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-nightly-archive-keyring.gpg https://brave-browser-apt-nightly.s3.brave.com/brave-browser-nightly-archive-keyring.gpg
```

Or you can remove the repository by removing its list file:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-nightly.list
```

Comment: I don't get the downvote, this answer provides more info.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the sources file:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-nightly.list
```

and the error will be gone.