# created by dnf config-manager from https://brave-browser-rpm-release.s3.brave.com/x86_64/ Fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, terminal, package-management, dnf

Whenever I try to install or update any package it starts to update the brave browser

```
created by dnf config-manager from https://brave-browser-rpm-release.s3.brave.com/x86_64/
```

I just removed the brave browser completely from my Operating System but still, it's updating it. how I can remove this configuration method

I tried to remove it by using `dnf clean all` but it did not work

I also tried this method but it's for ubuntu
[Brave browser - sudo apt-get error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/672241/brave-browser-sudo-apt-get-error). I am using Fedora 35

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you installed the Brave Browser repo, you probably ran the following command:

```
dnf config-manager --add-repo=https://brave-browser-rpm-release.s3.brave.com/x86_64/
```

When `dnf` created the repo, the “name” in the repo definition is the string you are seeing. What you see every time you run `dnf` commands is it pulling the repository metadata. It prints out the name of each repo as it gathers repo metadata. Despite the fact that you removed the browser package, the dnf repository is still installed on your system.

If you want it to not use the brave browser repo anymore, either delete the repo file or disable it by setting “enabled=0” in the repo file.